# How to check which application will open when I click on Launcher Icon?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

How to find which application Ubuntu is trying to open when I click on the launcher icon? Is there a file that I can check?

[image]

**NOTE**: I know that I can simply click on the icon and wait for the application to open but it is not working that way. When I click on the icon, nothing is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run the following command and find the `.desktop` file associated to the launcher

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

(I presume the *unknown* app icon is pinned to the Unity launcher).

Then look for the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`. Once you found the correct `.desktop` file, open it with a text-editor and look for the `Exec=` line. That should tell you about the application.

Comment: `No such schema 'com.canonical.unity.launcher'` I am getting this when I run the command.

Comment: @javanoob I fixed the command (case-sensitivity), check it now.

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you for your time. It worked.