# Ubuntu 21.04/GNOME/Mutter -- no right click menu for launcher/icon options?

Tags: unity, icons, launcher, .desktop, file-properties

If there's one thing that keeps on bugging me with GNOME on Ubuntu Desktop (21.04 at the moment, this was already in a few previous versions as well) is the lack of getting properties of an icon (and possibly remove it, modify it, etc) with a right-click menu option.

Example: every so often one ends up with this example situation where you have a "ghost" of another install, which in some cases has been already removed from the system altogether, but the non-working icon is still haunting and cluttering up the window manager somewhere:

[image: double icon]

[image: right-click menu]

Am I the only Ubuntu Desktop user in the world who finds it *extremely* infuriating when you don't have a right-click menu option to view the icon's properties, actual file location / exec command ... *anything?!* Feels like the developers dropped the ball on that one.

Whereas this is a default in Xfce for instance, on Ubuntu Desktop, not even UI add-ons such as ArcMenu have that option -- the only way around this issue is to start searching for the icon's .desktop file manually over in terminal and and then rm it.

What am I missing here, or is this really the way it's supposed to be? Any workaround suggestions?

EDIT: Sorry if I sound rude, but this has apparently been an issue for at least since 2018 [ https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012102/how-to-check-which-application-will-open-when-i-click-on-launcher-icon ].

So, what I'm looking for is right click => a "Properties" menu option => brings up the same properties view as i.e. CTRL+I in Nautilus. I haven't found any solution for this so far, should I just start stabbing the code myself (and although this would be the least preferred method, where should I start from)?

All help kindly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It depends upon the method of uninstall. If properly using Snap or Deb tools, then the "ghost" should not be there...that's a bug, please report it properly with sufficient detail that others can duplicate it reliably. Advice: Your bug report should be calm and professional; don't castigate the developers. They want their software to work properly -- *help* them.

Comment: @user535733 Yes, I'm well aware of that install/uninstall ordeal. Like I mentioned, my biggest problem is the fact that there's no right-click context menu to bring out the launcher/icon properties. Xfce and other window managers have it, why not Unity? If someone can point out what part of the code the right-click menu is, I can probably just code it in there myself.